# How are iPhone apps able to generate notifications while in standby?

Tags: iphone, ios4, push-notification

I'm a bit confused.
It says on many places, that on IOS you can't make your app work if the phone enters standby mode unless you use push notifications.

I did encounter some apps that do succeed this in IPhone 4
(such as ihandy alarm clock http://www.ihandysoft.com/alarm_clock.html)

It even beeped on standby when I was in airplane mode!

Can someone straighten my thought regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of notification in iOS: push notification and local notification.
In your case, the app beeps while airplane mode is on, it might use local notification rather than push notification.

Comment: You are probably right.
As I understand there is no way using my app in the background sampling some sensors, right?

Comment: Except you develop following kinds of apps - audio player, geo location informer, VoIP app, Newsstand app, and some accessories receiver.

Comment: I'm confused. I think you want to know how to get some message in background mode, right? The example ["alarm clock"](http://www.ihandysoft.com/alarm_clock.html) seems not run in background, but "schedule" a time to notify itself...

Comment: actually what I really want is to sample a sensor in the background (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692465/sampling-sensors-on-iphone-4-during-standby) 
posted it on different question because you did answer my question correctly

Comment: If you want to sample a sensor in the background, I think [Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html, “Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories” can continue to run in the background.