# sampling sensors on IPhone 4 during standby

Tags: iphone, ios4

I would like to be able to write an app that samples some sensor (not GPS) on IPhone 4, even when the phone is on standby mode

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on `EAAccessory` and `EASession`. You’re supposed to be able to get updates from accessories even when in the background.